# Add empty entry to combobox bound to entity list

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, combobox

I use a ComboBox which is bound to a List<> of Entities. How can I add a "Not selected" entry to the combobox? Adding null to the list results in empty combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an empty string or other unique text pattern instead of null.

And then You can handle the Format event of the Combobox to intercept the `<empty>` and display an alternate text.

```
private void comboBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
   e.Value = FormatForCombobox(e.ListItem);
}


private string FormatForCombobox(object value)
{
  string v = (string) value;
  if (v == string.Empty)
     v = "<no Selection>";
  return v;
}
```

Comment: I can't add anything to the combobox because it is bound to the list of entities.

Comment: You can still add an event when it's bound.

Comment: I can't add anything to the combobox because it is bound to the list of entities.

Comment: You add a special item to the List<> and an eventhandler to the Combobox.

Comment: That special item should be entity object. So how do I create a fake entity object? What entity key should it have?

Comment: Yes, try to create a special entity, the Key should be an recognizable (invalid) value. If that doesn't work you may need to copy entities to the .Items, and again use Format

Comment: Could you possibly extend the combo box class? The binding happens behind the scenes, I wonder if you could override those methods that populate it.. Might be a bit difficult. I wouldn't recommend creating an empty entity here and there... my 2 cents.

Answer (score 7):

If you're binding to `IEnumerable` list of entities you can certainly add your empty object manually.

For example

```
var qry = from c in Entities
          select c;
var lst = qry.ToList();

var entity = new Entity();
entity.EntityId= -1;
entity.EntityDesc = "(All)";
lst.Insert(0, entity);

MyComboBox.DataSource = lst;
MyComboBox.DisplayMember = "EntityDesc"
MyComboBox.ValueMember = "EntityId"
```